# It has an error while converting it to apk

Tags: python, tkinter, apk

ı want to convert my program from py to apk but i dont have any idea

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
root=tk.Tk()
def b1():
   b1.configure(bg='green'
b1=tk.Button(root,text='print')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error missing bracket and grid or pack or place.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
root=tk.Tk()
def b1():
   b1.configure(bg='green') #<== brace bracket
b1=tk.Button(root,text='print')
b1.pack() #<== add layout.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://avionmission.github.io/blog/convert-py-to-apk-using-python-and-buildozer/